# Return only updated result PHP

Tags: php

I was wondering how to detect when a page gets updated with PHP. I've researched things on Google, but came across nothing.

What I want to do is call a specific function when a page gets updated. I will be running a cron job in order to run the code.

I want something like this:

```
$contents = file_get_contents('example.com/page');
$Pupdate = file_get_contents('pageupdate.txt');

if ($Pupdate == ($pageUpdate = $contents)) {
  // the content is the same
} else {
  // the page has been updated, do whatever you need to do
  // and store the new updated content only in the file
  $fp = fopen('pageupdate.txt', 'w');
  fwrite($fp, $pageUpdate);
  fclose($fp);
}
```

If I can't do something like that then I want to at least know how to detect when a page gets updated in txt and return only updated result with PHP.

Please help, thanks!

Comment: It appears that you try to request an external website via php. Since you also state to run a cron, all you need to is to compare the content with the old one. To fetch the difference, look up diffing libraries.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running the script with cron, could you simply check if the file has been updated since the script was last run?

1. Get the last modified time of the file with [filetime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filemtime.php)
2. Check if the time now - last modified time is < the cron interval
3. If it is, "do whatever you need to do"